# ProGuard - leave only one class in package

Tags: java, proguard

I have package with 10 classes, one of them "ClassX" I need keep (because if I change it name then all old serialized object will not work) but if I add this one class ("ClassX") to exceptions then that 9 classes are still in this same package, but I want to move all classes to one package except only this one class ("ClassX").

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The option `-allowaccessmodification` should allow classes to be moved to the default package.

Comment: I can't use it for some reason. it's throws errors about "IllegalArgumentException ... UnknownIntegerValue", but I don't have any int fields/values in this part of code. (constructor of my class)

Comment: If ProGuard throws an exception, the input may be corrupt or there may be a bug. Try the latest version of ProGuard, and report a bug on its bug tracker (https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/) if necessary.